# TypeError: start() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)?

Tags: python, multithreading, arguments, typeerror

**I have something like this:**

```
class thread1(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        file = open("/home/antoni4040/file.txt", "r")
        data = file.read()
        num = 1
        while True:
           if str(num) in data:
               clas = ExportToGIMP
               clas.update()
           num += 1     
thread = thread1
        thread.start()
        thread.join()
```

**And I get this error:**

```
TypeError: start() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

**Why?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`thread = thread1` needs to be `thread = thread1()`. Otherwise you're trying to call methods on the class, rather than an actual instance of the class.

---

Also, don't override `__init__` on a Thread object to do your work - override [`run`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.run).

(While you can override `__init__` to do setup, that's not actually run in a thread, and needs to call `super()` as well.)

---

Here's how your code should look:

```
class thread1(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        file = open("/home/antoni4040/file.txt", "r")
        data = file.read()
        num = 1
        while True:
           if str(num) in data:
               clas = ExportToGIMP
               clas.update()
           num += 1     

thread = thread1()
        thread.start()
        thread.join()
```

Answer (score 3):

When you write

```
thread = thread1
```

you are assigning to `thread` the class `thread1`, i.e. `thread` becomes synonymous of `thread1`. For this reason, if you then write `thread.start()` you get that error - you are calling an instance method without passing `self`

What you actually want is to *instantiate* `thread1`:

```
thread = thread1()
```

so `thread` becomes an instance of `thread1`, on which you can call instance methods like `start()`.

By the way, the correct way to use `threading.Thread` is to override the `run` method (where you write the code that is to be run in another thread), not (just) the constructor.